# VST host playback timing issues (VST.NET + NAudio)

Tags: c#, midi, host, naudio, vst

I'm just getting started in trying to work out VST plugin hosting for a small music program that I've been working on for a while. I've now reached the point where I'm able to take melodies stored within my program and send the midi data to a hosted plugin (using VST.NET) and outputting the audio to WaveOut (NAudio). The problem is that the audio output is playing far too quickly and also not in time.

Here's the code that I'm using for playback, parts of which are based on the example host within the VST.NET sample projects:

```
public class PhraseEditorWaveProvider : VstWaveProvider
{

    public PhraseEditor PhraseEditor { get; private set; }


    public Rational PlaybackBeat { get; private set; }


    public PhraseEditorWaveProvider(PhraseEditor phraseEditor, string pluginPath, WaveFormat waveFormat = null)
        : base(pluginPath, waveFormat)
    {
        PhraseEditor = phraseEditor;
    }



    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        decimal framesPerBeat = (60 / (decimal)PhraseEditor.Phrase.Tempo) * WaveFormat.SampleRate;

        Rational startBeat = PlaybackBeat;
        Rational endBeat = startBeat + Rational.FromDecimal(count / framesPerBeat);

        //Get list of note starts and note ends that occur within the beat range
        List<VstEvent> vstEvents = new List<VstEvent>();
        foreach(Note note in PhraseEditor.Phrase.Notes)
        {
            if(note.StartBeat >= startBeat && note.StartBeat < endBeat)
                vstEvents.Add(NoteOnEvent(1, (byte)note.Pitch.Value, 100, (int)(note.Duration * framesPerBeat), (int)((note.StartBeat - startBeat) * framesPerBeat)));

            if(note.EndBeat >= startBeat && note.EndBeat < endBeat)
                vstEvents.Add(NoteOffEvent(1, (byte)note.Pitch.Value, (int)((note.EndBeat - startBeat) * framesPerBeat)));
        }

        foreach(Chord chord in PhraseEditor.Phrase.Chords)
        {
            if(chord.StartBeat >= startBeat && chord.StartBeat < endBeat)
            {
                //Play each note within a chord in the 4th octave, with velocity 70
                foreach (Pitch pitch in chord.Pitches)
                    vstEvents.Add(NoteOnEvent(1, (byte)((pitch.Value % 12) + 48), 70, (int)(chord.Duration * framesPerBeat), (int)((chord.StartBeat - startBeat) * framesPerBeat)));
            }
            if(chord.EndBeat >= startBeat && chord.EndBeat < endBeat)
            {
                foreach(Pitch pitch in chord.Pitches)
                    vstEvents.Add(NoteOffEvent(1, (byte)((pitch.Value % 12) + 48), (int)((chord.EndBeat - startBeat) * framesPerBeat)));
            }
        }
        PlaybackBeat = endBeat;

        return base.Read(vstEvents.OrderBy(x => x.DeltaFrames).ToArray(), buffer, offset, count);
    }

}

public abstract class VstWaveProvider : IWaveProvider
{

    private WaveFormat _waveFormat;
    public WaveFormat WaveFormat
    {
        get
        {
            return _waveFormat;
        }
        set
        {
            _waveFormat = value;
            BytesPerWaveSample = _waveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8;
        }
    }

    public VstPluginContext VstContext { get; private set; }

    public int BytesPerWaveSample { get; private set; }



    public VstWaveProvider(VstPluginContext vstContext, WaveFormat waveFormat = null)
    {
        WaveFormat = (waveFormat == null) ? new WaveFormat(44100, 2) : waveFormat;
        VstContext = vstContext;
    }

    public VstWaveProvider(string pluginPath, WaveFormat waveFormat = null)
    {
        WaveFormat = (waveFormat == null) ? new WaveFormat(44100, 2) : waveFormat;
        VstContext = OpenPlugin(pluginPath);
    }


    public abstract int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count);


    protected int Read(VstEvent[] vstEvents, byte[] outputBuffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        VstAudioBufferManager inputBuffers = new VstAudioBufferManager(
            VstContext.PluginInfo.AudioInputCount,
            count / (Math.Max(1, VstContext.PluginInfo.AudioInputCount) * BytesPerWaveSample)
        );

        return Read(inputBuffers, vstEvents, outputBuffer, offset, count);
    }


    protected int Read(VstAudioBufferManager inputBuffers, VstEvent[] vstEvents, byte[] outputBuffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        VstAudioBufferManager outputBuffers = new VstAudioBufferManager(
            VstContext.PluginInfo.AudioOutputCount,
            count / (VstContext.PluginInfo.AudioOutputCount * BytesPerWaveSample)
        );

        VstContext.PluginCommandStub.StartProcess();
        if(vstEvents.Length > 0)
            VstContext.PluginCommandStub.ProcessEvents(vstEvents);
        VstContext.PluginCommandStub.ProcessReplacing(inputBuffers.ToArray(), outputBuffers.ToArray());
        VstContext.PluginCommandStub.StopProcess();

        //Convert from multi-track to interleaved data
        int bufferIndex = offset;
        for (int i = 0; i < outputBuffers.BufferSize; i++)
        {
            foreach (VstAudioBuffer vstBuffer in outputBuffers)
            {
                Int16 waveValue = (Int16)((vstBuffer[i] + 1) * 128);
                byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(waveValue);
                outputBuffer[bufferIndex] = bytes[0];
                outputBuffer[bufferIndex + 1] = bytes[1];
                bufferIndex += 2;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }


    private VstPluginContext OpenPlugin(string pluginPath)
    {
        HostCommandStub hostCmdStub = new HostCommandStub();
        hostCmdStub.PluginCalled += new EventHandler<PluginCalledEventArgs>(HostCmdStub_PluginCalled);

        VstPluginContext ctx = VstPluginContext.Create(pluginPath, hostCmdStub);

        ctx.Set("PluginPath", pluginPath);
        ctx.Set("HostCmdStub", hostCmdStub);

        ctx.PluginCommandStub.Open();
        ctx.PluginCommandStub.MainsChanged(true);

        return ctx;
    }


    private void HostCmdStub_PluginCalled(object sender, PluginCalledEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }


    protected VstMidiEvent NoteOnEvent(byte channel, byte pitch, byte velocity, int noteLength, int deltaFrames = 0)
    {
        return new VstMidiEvent(deltaFrames, noteLength, 0, new byte[] { (byte)(144 + channel), pitch, velocity, 0 }, 0, 0);
    }


    protected VstMidiEvent NoteOffEvent(byte channel, byte pitch, int deltaFrames = 0)
    {
        return new VstMidiEvent(deltaFrames, 0, 0, new byte[] { (byte)(144 + channel), pitch, 0, 0 }, 0, 0);
    }

}
```

Which would get called by the following:

```
WaveOut waveOut = new WaveOut(WaveCallbackInfo.FunctionCallback());
waveOut.Init(new PhraseEditorWaveProvider(this, @"C:\Users\james\Downloads\Cobalt\Cobalt\Cobalt 64bit\Cobalt.dll"));
waveOut.Play();
```

Where Cobalt is the current plugin that I'm using for testing.

For context, Rational is my own data type since other parts of my program are doing lots of manipulation of melodies and I found that doubles and decimals weren't giving me the precision that I required.

Also, both the VST plugin context and WaveOut are set to have sample rates of 44.1kHz, so there shouldn't need to be any up/down-sampling when passing the plugin output data into the WaveOut buffer.

I'm at a complete loss as to why the audio is playing back faster than expected. It seems to be roughly 4x faster than expected. If anyone can give any pointers what may be causing this I'd be hugely grateful.

With it playing out of time, I suspect that this is down to me not understanding correctly how the deltaFrame property works within VstMidiEvent. I've tried playing around with both deltaFrame and noteOffset, though don't seem to be having much luck with either, I'm currently working under the assumption that they measure the number of audio frames from the start of the current block of data, to the time of the event within that block. Unfortunately I've been struggling to find much useful documentation on this so it could be that I'm totally wrong about this though.

Look forward to any responses

Kind regards

James

Comment: With two channels and 16 bits per sample, one frame has four bytes.

Comment: DeltaFrames are the number of frames (think FrameRate) offset from the start of the current cycle. Also you should create the VstAudioBufferManager only once and reuse its buffers - otherwise performance suffers resulting in possible audio glitches.

Comment: @obiwanjacobi I've seen this definition of deltaFrames a few times, to clarify, each call to ProcessReplacing essentially corresponds to one cycle, correct? Also, from what I can understand on the definition of noteOffset, that's basically like deltaFrames but measured from the start of the note isn't it? So if I'm already defining deltaFrames for my events then I can ignore noteOffset? Also, thanks, yeah I thought I should probably move that VstAudioBufferManager, I'm still very much figuring out the correct way to use your library

Comment: @CL I believe I'm already accounting for this, since the VST buffer size is number of bytes required by the WaveOut, divided by number of channels and number of bytes per sample. When actually writing to the WaveOut buffer, I'm getting 2 bytes per channel per sample, for a total of 4 bytes per sample

Comment: Yep, a cycle is one time around the block, calling ProcessEvents and ProcessReplacing with a specific (block) size buffers. If your BlockSize is small you can just leave DeltaFrames zero - that small timing error is usually not audible. I don't remember the use of the other fields,(noteOffset) I think it was very specific - you do not need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I found what was causing the problem, it was in this section of code:

```
public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    decimal framesPerBeat = (60 / (decimal)PhraseEditor.Phrase.Tempo) * WaveFormat.SampleRate;

    Rational startBeat = PlaybackBeat;
    Rational endBeat = startBeat + Rational.FromDecimal(count / framesPerBeat);
    ...
}
```

Which I just changed to this:

```
public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
    decimal framesPerBeat = (60 / (decimal)PhraseEditor.Phrase.Tempo) * WaveFormat.SampleRate;
    int samplesRequired = count / (WaveFormat.Channels * (WaveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8));

    Rational startBeat = PlaybackBeat;
    Rational endBeat = startBeat + Rational.FromDecimal(samplesRequired / framesPerBeat);
    ...
}
```

Dumb mistake on my part, I'd been converting from bit-rate to sample-rate everywhere except in my method for getting upcoming midi events. My audio is now playing at a rate far closer to what I'd expect, and seems to be more reliable on the timing, though I haven't had a chance to fully test this yet.